# why this is an infinite JavaScript for loop : can't fix the bug

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a javascript interview question, but I can't slove it, can anyone help?

**question**: 
Function appendChildren should add a new child div to each existing div. New divs should be decorated by calling decorateDiv.

For example, after appendChildren is executed, the following divs:
    // Example case.

```js
    document.body.innerHTML = `
    <div id="a">
      <div id="b">
      </div>
    </div>`;
```

should take the following form (assuming decorateDiv does nothing):

```html
 <div id="a">
      <div id="b">
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
```

The code below should do the job, but for some reason it goes into an infinite loop. Fix the bugs.

```js
function appendChildren(decorateDivFunction) {
  var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

  for (var i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    decorateDivFunction(newDiv);
    allDivs[i].appendChild(newDiv);
  }
}

// Example case. 
document.body.innerHTML = `
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
  </div>
</div>`;

//appendChildren(function(div) {});
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

[the origin of the test can be found here(question 6)](https://www.testdome.com/d/javascript-interview-questions/2)

Comment: At what point will `i < allDivs.length` be `false`?  That is, if you step through this code line by line as it executes, why do you think the loop *shouldn't* be infinite?

Comment: @David well the fact that appending to the DOM will update the node list isn't super obvious. I found it astonishing when I learned that a really long time ago; it just seemed like such a bizarre way to do things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `allDivs` list is a *live NodeList*.  That means that every time you create a new `<div>` and add it to the page, the list will be instantly updated to include that new element. Thus, the loop will continue forever.

You can use `Array.from()` in new environments to make a plain Array copy:

```
var allDivs = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("div"));
```

Or you can use this, which should work anywhere:

```
var allDivs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("div"));
```

The plain array will of course *not* be instantly updated to include each new `<div>` you create.

Comment: A simpler solution would be to just cache the length of the NodeList. `for (var i = 0, len = allDivs.length; i < len; i++)`

Comment: @skyline3000 well that *might* work, but the list doesn't necessarily put the newly-added elements at the end. The way the code is written, they would probably end up in the middle of the list. (I'm pretty sure the list is maintained in DOM traversal order.)

Comment: I don't want to spur an argument here but saying it *might* work is simply not correct - it will definitely work. In fact, it works the same way as your solution so I'm not quite sure why you would say it might not work. The collection of elements is the same - yours just isn't a live reference to the DOM. This technique has been around for ages and is well-documented in books like "High Performance JavaScript". The elements will not be added in the middle of the list (that really doesn't even make sense). You can test it yourself here http://jsfiddle.net/7joxu89L/3/

Comment: @skyline3000 [here's a fork showing what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/xn7qjd2a/4/) - your test was too simple. Note that in the fork, no new content is added to elements "c", "d", or "e", but new content *is* added to the generated elements.

Comment: @skyline3000 [now here's a fork using my approach](http://jsfiddle.net/x02np3Lf/2/). The difference should be obvious.

Comment: The thing about live node lists is that when the DOM changes, they're updated as if they were re-created from scratch again. Thus, since the list is built from a depth-first in-order traversal, newly-added elements show up in the list as if they had been in the DOM already.

Comment: I see your point, I didn't think that's what the OP was asking for (I guess we should have seen where the OP wanted "c", "d", "e", etc). I assumed more levels of hierarchy in the original tree, not separate tree nodes, in which case your solution is needed (fwiw `querySelectorAll()` also returns a non-live nodelist).

Comment: @skyline3000 yes and I suspect `.querySelectorAll()` being newer does not return a live list because the "live" thing is so completely weird, and seriously violates the "rule of least surprise".